# Rotate certificate for kubernetes in a KOPS managed cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I've launched a couple clusters through [KOPS](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) and, being new to provisioning k8s clusters, shared the entire kube config file with my team. I had assumed incorrectly that I could easily change username and password to prevent developers that have left the company from authenticating if they had the kube config file.

The sample user section looks something like this:

```
- name: kubernetes.example.com
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
    password: REDACTED
    username: REDACTED
```

When I change the password, I can still authenticate. But removing the certificate sections I become unauthorized. I've set up [aws-iam-authenticator](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator) and that is working perfectly, but the certificate authentication still works indicating that anyone with access to the original kube config would still be able to authenticate with the server.

Is there any easy way outside of relaunching a new cluster to rotate these certificates or turn off certificate authentication altogether and just defer to AWS authentication?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no easy way to roll certificates without disruptions. See https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/rotate-secrets/

It is also not possible to disable certificates as kubernetes itself relies on the PKI to authenticate.

The good news is that in later versions of kOps, rotating secrets *should* be graceful. There is a PR here for this functionality here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/pull/10516

Comment: Right now this feature is available https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/operations/rotate-secrets/, however after I rotated the keypair `kubecfg` is not rotated. If I try creating a new keypair, it throws this error: `Error: adding keypair to "kubecfg" is not supported`. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: There is no keypair called kubecfg. The list of keypairs can be seen using `kops get keypair`

Comment: Yes. It is very weird that one of the old clusters has it. Maybe it was sth someone added manually